# How to get blob data from blob:chrome-extension?

Tags: javascript, node-webkit

I'm trying to use this in an image.src..

"blob:chrome-extension://enjilmhmplefekkpbciadkljojpakhmd/cb5a1692-5194-4a3d-afd4-85b27445de94"

That is retrieved from a js library I'm using that loads a local file with binary data..
However, I need to get the blob data to convert it to a dataurl (I think)..

How do I get the blob data using javascript? (I'm also using nw.js if that matters)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL This might help you.

Comment: I tried filereader, but it gives error: "TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'."

Comment: seems like somewhere in my library it is doing a URL.revokeObjectURL( sourceURI ); on it, so I guess that removes the image before I can use the data??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NW.js and there is an actual file, just use the Node.js File System module.

```html
<img id="cat">
<script>
  const fs = window.nw.require('fs');
  const path = window.nw.require('path');

  function getImageURI (imagePath) {
    try {
      const imageData = fs.readFileSync(imagePath);
      return 'data:image/png;base64,' + imageData.toString('base64');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error reading image', error);
    }
  }

  const catImage = path.join('.', 'some-folder', 'cat.png');
  const catURI = getImageURI(catImage);
  const cat = document.getElementById('cat');
  cat.src = catURI;
</script>
```